# qtip on google markers

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, qtip2

I am trying to add qtip tooltips to my google markers, so when the marker is clicked it opens the tooltip.

I can get it working on other elements because I can select their ID like so:

```
$('#header').qtip()
```

But google markers are different. I tried adding an idea to their object like so:

```
marker.metadata = {id: 'marker1'};
```

or:

```
marker.set("id", 'marker1');
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

I was using InfoBubble before which worked fine, but due to the map being small I need the tooltip to not be restricted to the map itself.